# Browser blocks Web site secured by Azure AD

Tags: https, azure-active-directory, ssl-certificate

I have a web site secured by Azure AD which has recently become broken.

When a user logs in, the interaction with AAD works fine but at the last step the browser would decide to block the web site URL with the message below. The URL remains blocked until cookies and site data are cleared.

The behavior is not universal but may be related to certain hosts - it works fine when I host the web site on my laptop (Windows 10 Enterprise), but has the problem when hosted on the dev VM (Windows Server 2016).

I suspect it might be cert related, but am confused about the fact that the browser accepts the URL in the first message but later (after AAD interaction) decides to consider that the website no longer trusted.

The screenshots and message trace are captured with Firefox, but other browsers have the same behavior.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of the login message traces. HAR trace can be download from here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuD-2O_ZRWVimBlh5fL24LQBHeWS?e=2V95ib

[image]

Comment: it could be a certificate issue, but it seems like a misconfiguration in your MSAL code which is unable to process the information received by the callback endpoint `testdev-signin-oidc`

Comment: The code that runs on the dev VM and my laptop are the same so I'd expect the way callback endpoint is processed is the same.

Comment: In addition, only one registered app has the described problem, but the application works fine with another registered app in the same tenant.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the working app and broken app, several differences were found. The reported issue went away after I removed the token configuration below from the broken app:

[image]

Comment: glad you were able to solve this.